# Here Maps SDK issue on Android 6.0

Tags: android, here-api

I'm having some issues displaying the Here Maps (SDK version 3.0.2) on Marshmallow devices.

The application is built agains Marshmallow, so it includes the new Permission System.

Even if all the permissions are enabled (double checked within Settings, Location and Storage are both on) the map initialisation fails with the MISSING PERMISSION exception: `Unable to initialise map: MISSING_PERMISSION`. It works fine on any other Android version.

Is anyone else facing similar issues when compiling agains Marshmallow?
If so, is there a workaround?

UPDATE: It's fixed in SDK version 3.1.0

Comment: Are you sure that there are no other `dangerous` permissions that Here Maps might need? You might check your final APK's manifest (either looking in `build/` of your app module in Android Studio, or via `aapt dump badging` at the command line) to confirm exactly what permissions are being requested there.

Comment: @CommonsWare You would see them under the App Settings anyway, where you could manually enable / disable them. It works fine Pre-Marshmallow, checked settings and both are enabled on my Marshmallow device as well - and there's nothing else.

Comment: "You would see them under the App Settings anyway, where you could manually enable / disable them" -- excellent point, I wasn't thinking about that.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with the HERE Maps SDK for Android and will be fixed in an upcoming release. As you discovered, building with a target API level of 22 or lower will work around the issue. Apologies for the inconvenience!

Comment: Are you part of the Here Maps SDK team? Is there an official way to report and track these issues? Thanks.